# How to add a Fragment with a different class to my MainActivity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm working on adding a fragment to my Main Activity which will show a Google Map.

What I want to achieve?

- I want the added fragment to have another corresponding Java class to it.

This is the xml file for my MainActivity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.jovan.APPNAME.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.jovan.APPNAME.MapsActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want the fragment to have a it's own java class. This is the Java class.

```
public class MapsActivity extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

Here is also the Java class for the Main Activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer);

        setTitle("");

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {


        }

        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

However as it is right now it does not work. I assume that the fragment isn't found. Any idea how i can fix this and make it work. Thanks in advice.

**UPDATE**

I suspect that my fragment and the class aren't wired up property.
I tried to make all the changes that are provided by the answers but then I got a black screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fragment you named the reference  `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"`

But your Fragment is called MapsActivity

```
public class MapsActivity extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
```

Comment: Should I rename the Fragment or the Java class ?

Comment: The fragment, and use the package name of your actual project

Should be something like com.jovan.APPNAME.SupportMapFragment

Comment: Ok but when I use com.jovan.APPNAME.SupportMapFragment for the name of my fragment it says that I have unresolved class.

Comment: remove the name, press ctrl+space in  the android studio and select your fragment from the list

Comment: That is what I actually  did but I got black screen.

Answer (score 1):

Change your fragment to this:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    class="com.jovan.APPNAME.MapsActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

You shouldn't name your `Fragment` class as `MapsActivity` as it is confusing.

Comment: I got black screen after I changed it.

Comment: What you see depends on your fragment layout that you inflate. Try placing a `Toast` message inside `onCreateView` of your fragment so that you know that the fragment is working